# Can I run mongodb under a Managed Service Account

Tags: windows, mongodb, managed-service-accounts

I'm trying to run MongoDB under a Windows Managed Service Account. This works fine for memcached on the same server, but when I run the MongoDB account I get this:

```
Windows could not start the MongoDB ervice on Local Computer.

Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

Adjusting the file permissions so the account can write (or have fullcontrol) inside the MongoDb directory (where binaries, logs and data is stored gave me this:

```
Windows could not start the MongoDB on Local Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log. If this is a non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 100.
```

The log file now says this:

```
exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: C:\data\db\mongod.lock
```

So, obviously I had a remaining mongod.exe running.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions, file locks and all such things must match.

I figured the above out as I was asking the question and detailing every step.

Thanks for the rubber ducking! :)